# Консольное приложение на Python

Tags: python

Господа, посоветуйте решение для реализации консольного приложения на python.
Основная цель - выбор объектов из списка строк нажатием клавиши, напр. `<TAB>`

Спасибо.

Comment: [python-prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit) для этого хорошо подходит

Answer (score 4):

Видимо придется начать с классики - [ncurses](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html). Для него есть обвязки под многие языки, в том числе и питон.

Есть альтернативные проекты - [npyscreen](https://code.google.com/p/npyscreen/) и [urwid.org](http://urwid.org/).